# PFObject has no member objectforkey

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Here's my code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    state = .DefaultMode

    // fill the cache of a user's followees
    ParseHelper.getFollowingUsersForUser(PFUser.currentUser()!) { (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        let relations = results
        // use map to extract the User from a Follow object
        self.followingUsers = relations.map {
            $0.objectForKey(ParseHelper.ParseFollowToUser) as! PFUser
        }
    }
}
```

My error:

> Value of type '[PFObject]' has no member 'objectForKey'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess its because the [PFObjects] array is optional and hasn't been unwrapped yet.

```
if let relations = results {
    // use map to extract the User from a Follow object
    self.followingUsers = relations.map {
        $0.objectForKey(ParseHelper.ParseFollowToUser) as! PFUser
    }
}
```

Comment: if let results = results { ... } is still creating a second object, you are just naming yours the same as the passed in results object.

Comment: There is absolutely no strict way on what you name your unwrapped variable in swift, Apple give no guidance. Code convention wise i get you argument, but at the end of the day the name of the unwrapped variable doesn't matter.